# ASP.NET map model type to repository type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I was wondering if it is possible to map a model type to a repository type with C#/ASP.NET. As you see, I am trying to implement the repository/unit of work pattern. A sample implementation is shown below:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;

    public DepartmentRepository DepartmentRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.departmentRepository == null)
            {
                this.departmentRepository = new DepartmentRepository(context);
            }
            return departmentRepository;
        }
    }

    public CourseRepository CourseRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.courseRepository == null)
            {
                this.courseRepository = new CourseRepository(context);
            }
            return courseRepository;
        }
    }
```

It has a problem however, that the UnitOfWork needs to keep a long list of properties for each repository type. In this example it is not too bad since there are only two entity types(department, course) with two corresponding repositories(deparment repository and course repository). But as the size of the application grows, the UnitOfWork class quickly becomes big and messy with tens or even hundreds of properties, it will be none other than a god class.

What I'd want is something more generic, such as a generic method GetRepository() that maps a model type to a repository object. The below pseudo code demonstrates what I want:

```
// definition
public TRepository GetRepository<TModel>(){ // pending implementation } 

// use-case
var departmentRepository = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<TModel>();
```

So how can I write such code that maps a model type to a repository object? I am afraid AutoMapper will not work as it only maps between concrete implementations, not generic types. What do you think? How will you approach this problem when the condition is not to hard code every repository implementation as properties in unit of work?

Comment: Remove the repositories from the UnitOfWork. Inject UoW into the repositories and get the entity sets from the Context.

Comment: Looks a bit like a job for dependency injection & inversion of control. You would register all of the models and corresponding repository associations in your IOC bootstrapper ...

Comment: You can write your own mapper to solve this

Comment: @H.Herzl: I know I can, but I dont know how. If I do I wouldnt have asked this question.

Comment: I've added an asnwer, please check it and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an extension method like this:

```
public static class Mapper
{
    public static T Map<T>(Object source) where T : class
    {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.CanRead)
            {
                var sourceProperty = source.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);

                if (sourceProperty == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source);

                property.SetValue(instance, value);
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

If you want to map one class from another:

```
var foo = Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(new Customer { CustomerID = "ACME", CompanyName = "Acme Corp.", ContactName = "Jhon Doe" });
```

Output:

{CustomerViewModel}
    CompanyName: "Acme Corp."
    CustomerID: "ACME"

Assuming you have the following classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public String CustomerID { get; set; }

    public String CompanyName { get; set; }

    public String ContactName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public String CustomerID { get; set; }

    public String CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Also, this is a basic idea you can improve this extension method for mapping from dynamic object (ExpandoObject), dictionary (Dictionary<String, Object>) and create the mapping table for better performance in collection's mapping (big collections of items).

This method supports anonymous objects as well.

Please let me know if this answer is useful, we can improve the algorithm according to your requirements.

Comment: Well I know how to map a domain model to a view model already, just use automapper and it works. The question I have is, how to map two objects with unrelated properties/compositions but with similar naming convention. Lets say I have a domain model called 'UserModel' and its repository is called 'UserRepository', I want to map 'UserModel' to 'UserRepository'. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In this case, the name of classes do not matter only the properties names; have you tried modify this piece of code for support lambda expressions, maybe I miss something in your question and you want to map properties with different names